# When comparing two distributions, what is a 'low' value of a Kullback–Leibler divergence?

Tags: distributions, kullback-leibler

In essence how do we know a low value is good enough? Given the values could be 0 to infinity. Is a value X 'good' for any two distributions? (a little like R2 score is 'unites') Or could it be like MSE where the actual number has meaning relevant only to the data, e.g. a value of 0.1 be 'good' for two distributions, but bad for another two distributions?

In essence how do we know what is a good value, for distributions we are comparing?

Comment: The Kullback-Leibler distance does not have a absolute range to decide what is small and what is large. It depends on the distributions. For instance, take the distance between two normal distributions$$\log\frac{\tau_2}{\tau_1}+\frac{\tau_1^2+(\mu_1-\mu_2)^2}{2 \tau_2^2}-\frac12$$which is essentially scaled by $\tau_2$.

Comment: Thanks Xi'an! Therefore, how does one make sense of it at all? Currently I'm stuck as "as long as a piece of string". I have a 'distance' but don't know if far is far. Is there a way to extract more meaning if I know the two distributions, say? Thanks!